# How to store arabic text into MySQL database correctly from HTML form using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, arabic

I've searched a lot but with no avail!

```
>> After the PHP connection I put : mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);
>> The form input tag contains attribute : accept-charset="utf-8"
>> I'm sure that the database collation is : utf8_general_ci
>> I've the meta tag in the head : <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

What should I do now ?? The arabic text is stored like : Ø³Ù

Comment: Can you provide more code? Like what are the PHP codes you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, it was here :

```
$blog_title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($blog_title)));
```

I don't know what's the problem itself but when I removed it, it works well!

Answer (score 0):

I make the same but :
database collation is : utf8_defult collection
 small letters , I don't know if that problem

my data is saved in arabic
I hope I helped you